# Getting Facebook Photo from Photo ID

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am new to Facebook Graph API . I have a to read user photos so I am using GET query "me/photos/upload" then its returning me an array containing photos id :: id = "5556---------"  , now when i am using this id "/5556------" its again returning me the same photo id . 
 Can anyone tells me how to read image from that id ?
and also how to get a thumbnail from that image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the possible fields can be found in the API reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo

For example, this would return URLs: `/me/photos/uploaded?fields=images`